# show div on focus in and allow user to use option buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML form in a table that allows user to search or enter new details for staff. I would like to show a div when they select a input box. This I can do using

```
<td><input type="text" name="team" id="team" size="23" maxlength="4"  
onfocus="document.getElementById('show_teams').style.display='block';"
onblur="document.getElementById('show_teams').style.display='none';">
</td>
```

However as soon as the user try's to click an option box inside the Div it will closes ( due to onblur display none ) I have dabled with jquery and I think this is the way to go but I can't find a solution.

The basic idea is on selecting (focus) the "team" text box a div will show with 2 option and three drop down boxes. once selected the correct code for a shift pattern will be placed in the text box just cicked, and the div will hide. 
 Thanks

Comment: hint: you can make use of a global state variable.

Comment: if user enter something in div i.e input not empty than you can display him div

Answer (score 1):

I have just should with an example,

```
$('.myDiv').hide();    

$('#test1').focus(function(){
    $('.myDiv').show();
});

$('#my_select').change(function(){
    $('#test1').val($(this).val());
    $('.myDiv').hide();    
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpYdt/12/)

Change your html code in the div accordingly, should help you out.